# Best way to handle large amount of separate timed tasks in java?

Tags: java

I am developing a small multiplayer browser game with java as backend. Players will be able to create their own game rooms and have other players join them.

Every game room needs to have some sort of scheduled tasks implemented and I am not sure what is the best way to proceed in order to keep the game running smooth at a large scale.

The concept without going into too much details is that when a new round starts in a game room the next player in the list will type a question and the other players then have 30 seconds to answer the question before a new round starts.

So my problem is that I don't know what I should do to be able to have separate tasks such as checking if the player that asks the question is not inactive (should be skipped if not typing a question in 15 seconds or so), start a new round after 30 seconds etc.

I was initially going to create a separate thread for each game room, but realized that's probably not very smart. Another thought would be to have a main game loop running every second and check through all game rooms and execute tasks that way, but I am assuming it would eventually be too much to loop through if there are too many game rooms created.

What is the best way to handle timed events in multiple game rooms as described above without running into performance issues?

**Edit**

Is it better to have 1 loop for all game rooms or should each game room have a thread with its own loop?

Answer (score 0):

If your gameloop just checks for inactivity it probably can handle millions of rooms.

Otherwise I think you should look at [Tasks and ExecuterServices](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm). Java has great ways of distributing individual tasks onto the CPU-Cores evenly.

It is impossible to teach all the concurrent functionality in a single SO post. You need to learn it yourself

Comment: On top of checking for inactive users, it would also need to check if all the players in the room have answered the question and start a new round with a new question every 30 seconds. If one single loop iterating every 1 second can handle this at a large scale then that would make my life very easy. I am, however, not sure if this is preferable over having separate tasks for every single room.

Thanks for the answer, I will read up on this.